# Brackets is opposites at mono develop c++

Tags: mono, monodevelop

The brackets in mono develop is opposite.

this is image who explain that:

[image: code screenshot]

Comment: what version of monodevelop are you using? which OS do you have?

Comment: what version of monodevelop are you using?